# What is a react way to call rest api with post data?

Tags: python, rest

Say I have an API: http://localhost:123/amazon_api

In python I can call it with the following code, where `data` is just some values I want to pass to the API:

```
resp = requests.get(url, data={"optional1": optional1})
```

In react, there is a library called 'superagent' which seems to have similar functions:

```
Request.get(url, {"optional1": 1}).then((response) => {
    result = response;
});
```

However, it doesn't work as it seems the following cannot get passed in:

```
{"optional1": 1}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that caused by misused Superagent's API?

According to docs, what you're attempting won't work.

Do following following:

```
 request
   .get(url)
   // To transfer data over GET request, use query method
   .query({"optional1": 1})
   .then((response) => {
       //
   })
```

More info:
http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#get-requests